# Wookmark script making my Tumblr theme also scroll to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I just started using the Wookmark script and it's making my Tumblr theme overflow by also scrolling to the left when it should scroll vertically. This is what I have for now.

http://lt-neon.tumblr.com/

And the code is on this site.

http://pastebin.com/aZTpxX8C

Is there anyway I can solve this so that way my Tumblr theme scrolls vertically instead of horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, this issue isn't related to Wookmark. There are two elements on your page that are pushing the page width and creating the scroll.

The first is `div#search`. Remove `left: 770px` replace with `float: right`.

The second is `#content`. Again if you remove `left: 150px` the scroll disappears.

I am not 100% sure why your using `left:` to position elements, but this may be helpful: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Comment: Do you mean #wrapper for the second? I put position: relative; for the content.

Comment: I am not sure as the code seems to have changed. Either way it looks like you have the issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed everything.